# how to fix anaconda driver issue?

Tags: python, anaconda, gpu, driver, amd-gpu

```
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open radeonsi: /home/moritz/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/../../../libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so) (search paths /usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open radeonsi: /home/moritz/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/../../../libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so) (search paths /usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /home/moritz/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/../../../libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so) (search paths /usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I am using a Thinkpad E14 gen 2 with a Ryzen CPU, while plotting graphs or running pygame files, this error occurs, I tried solving it by reinstalling the mesa-loader, but nothing helped.

Comment: Adding `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` to the `.bashrc` file solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me when I had the exact same error.

```
cp /lib/libstdc++.so.6 ~/anaconda3/lib/
```

If that didn't work then try this:

```
cp "/lib/libstdc++.so.6" ~/anaconda3/lib/
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).